# Should an app be fully error free before publishing?

Tags: android-studio

My app has been test running without crashes for some weeks now. However, in Logcat there are 3 persistent errors (lines marked with "E"). I do not know how to solve them, but they do not appear to harm the proper functioning of the app.

```
E/zygote64: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.
```

How usual is it for developers to publish apps (like on Google Play) that knowingly have errors in them that don't seem to be "mission critical"?

Comment: [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) -> *"Logcat is a command-line tool that dumps a log of system messages, including stack traces when the device throws an error and messages that you have written from your app with the Log class."*   Also check your code for Log class usage how and why there are used.. Without seeing source code or the errors for that matter we also can't help..

Comment: if possibility of a user encounters the exception or crash is high .u should fix it before publish .

Comment: @RaymondNijland have added the errors (heb de errors toegevoegd).

Comment: Well a warning about not able to load a (64 bits) `libGLES_mali.so` sounds worrying as that seams to be a library for running  OpenGL ES  on 64bits [ARM CPU platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) .. So your application build could potentially fail to run on 64bits ARM Cpu's  .. I am assuming your application is a game as OpenGL is involved?

Answer (score 0):

The google play console has a 'Bad beheivour treshold' of '1.09%'.

This is calculated by: 'Percentage of daily sessions during which your users experienced at least one crash. A daily session refers to a day during which your app was used.'

So you should aim to have a lower crash rate of 1.09%. There will always be bugs in your app that you haven't encountered yet in in your tests so an app will (almost) never be completely crash free. So a lot of developers publish their apps while there are still (mostly unknown) error's in them.

Sadly enough I can't help you with your exact errors but I hope I have helped you with the Google Play Console Guidelines.